# Hide status bar only on modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, show-hide, statusbar

I have a view controller `A` that shows the status bar on top. From that view controller I want to present another view controller `B` that hides the status bar. In order to achieve that I override the property

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

on `B`. For enforcing a smooth animation whenever the status bar (dis)appears I also override the property

```
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}
```

However, when I now present view controller `B` from `A` the status bar disappears **abruptly** while `A` is still visible, right before the animated modal transition begins.

I'm searching for a way to **fix this "jumping status bar" behavior**. Ideally, I would like to have a clean separation:

- `A`: **shows** status bar
- `B`: **does not show** status bar

so that, when I present `B`, the status bar is covered by it.

As the status bar seems to be a global view that doesn't *belong* to any particular view controller it's probably difficult to achieve that kind of behavior. So in case it's not possible to replicate this exact animation behavior, I'd also be happy if the status bar slides out smoothly *during* the view controller transition. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

For animating the status bar during the transition, you could do something like this in view controller B:

```
var willAppear = false

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return willAppear
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    willAppear = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

Then I guess you would need to do the opposite if you want the reverse effect when the modal controller is dismissed.

You can adjust the duration of the animation to whatever suits you, though I'm not sure how consistent the duration between `viewWillAppear` and the modal controller actually being fully presented will be.

**EDIT:**

"Opposite" ends up being something like this (in view controller A):

```
var willAppear = false

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return willAppear
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let _ = presentedViewController as? B {
        willAppear = true
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    if let _ = presentedViewController as? B {
        willAppear = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
}
```

Which I agree, is way too much code for something that I imagine many people want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Half of it works, the other half (the "opposite" when dismissing the view controller) doesn't. It seems that you need to add code to _both_ view controllers participating in the transition in order to get a smooth slide-in _and_ slide-out animation for the status bar. I'll add another answer later to explain this approach. It's really annoying that Apple made this so complicated and doesn't animate the status bar automatically – I claim that in 99% of all cases this would the behavior that developers want.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified "opposite" better! I thought that might happen. The transition back seems like it would be a little trickier too. I think you might need to make use of `viewWillDisappear` as well as `viewWillAppear` and ensure that you're moving to the view controller that required status bar hidden before setting the flag. I will update my answer as well.